# How secure is ASP.NET Identity GenerateEmailConfirmationToken?

Tags: security, asp.net-identity

ASP.NET Identity 2.0 contains `GenerateEmailConfirmationToken` which can be used for generating a token for remind password or verify e-mail tasks. I know that tis token is created by using SecurityStamp of the user cryptographically and it is not stored in the database; it is verified by computing it once more.

I'm using it for email verification purpose. I want to login users after I verify the token. This is a practive I've used on Ruby on Rails before. However I have some reservations about the security of this approach.

Is it secure to login the users just by verifying this token? I will deny verification if the user email is already verified; thus this would be a one time thing. But I couln't be sure since I don't know all the inner working of GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync.

Answer (score 0):

The token is just one way to enhance your security. it's secure only to an extent so it's always good to have more ways to authenticate and authorize

Comment: I'm not talking about implementing all user security based on that token. I'm just talking about a specific part of the application and a specific course of action in that part; and I'm asking that specific course of action poses a weak spot. So I guess the question deserves a more specific answer.